# (UserForm) ListBox Change event is not firing when ListBox List property is updated by code

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I have a userform with a multi-column ListBox and a ComboBox. The ListBox by default shows a full set of data. The ComboBox contains values from one of the columns in the ListBox. Selection of a value from the ComboBox filters the ListBox data.

When this change to the ListBox happens, I want to Debug.Print "A message..." but with no success.

I get no error messages. The debugger doesn't even step through the ListBox_Change event procedure. I only have the above Debug.Print... line in the event procedure.

Your assistance for solutions/clues will be much appreciated.

**Question updated: Code shown below:**

```
Dim arrAllData() As Variant
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Call CentreForm(Me)

arrAllData = Range("tblData") 'Excel table of 11 columns

Me.lbxData.List = arrAllData

Set collProjName = UniqueItemsFromRanger(Range("tblData").Columns(2))

For i = 1 To collProjName.Count
    Me.cboProjName.AddItem collProjName(i)
Next i

End Sub

Private Sub cboProjName_Change()
Dim NewList() As Variant, NewListSingleRow(0 To 0, 0 To 10) As Variant
Dim colNbr As Integer

Erase NewList
If Me.cboProjName.Value <> "" Then
    With Me.lbxData
        NewList = .List

        NewList = FilterData(NewList, Me.cboProjName.Value, 2)
        If UBound(NewList, 2) > 0 Then
            .List = Application.Transpose(NewList)
        Else
            For i = 0 To UBound(NewList, 1)
                NewListSingleRow(0, i) = NewList(i, 0)
                .List = NewListSingleRow
            Next i
        End If
    End With
End If
End Sub

Private Sub lbxData_Change()
    Debug.Print "Test Message..."
End Sub

Function UniqueItemsFromRanger(Rng As Range) As Collection
Dim coll As New Collection, i As Long

On Error Resume Next
For i = 1 To Rng.Rows.Count
    coll.Add Item:=Rng.Cells(i, 1), Key:=CStr(Rng.Cells(i, 1))
Next i

Set UniqueItemsFromRanger = coll
End Function

Function FilterData(arrData() As Variant, FilterFor As String, ColumnToFilter 
As Long) As Variant
Dim arrDataFiltered() As Variant
Dim rowCount As Long, colCount As Long, filteredCount As Long
rowCount = UBound(arrData, 1)
colCount = UBound(arrData, 2)

filteredCount = 0

For i = 0 To rowCount
    If arrData(i, ColumnToFilter - 1) = FilterFor Then
        ReDim Preserve arrDataFiltered(0 To colCount, 0 To filteredCount)
        For j = 0 To colCount
            arrDataFiltered(j, filteredCount) = arrData(i, j)
        Next j
        filteredCount = filteredCount + 1
    End If
Next i

FilterData = arrDataFiltered

End Function
```

Comment: Hello.  Please post the code you have tried.  I suggest reading [Minimal Reprodudible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `ListBox1_Change` fires only when an item is selected in the listbox. Not when LB is cleared or an item is added.

Comment: You don't need to handle a `Change` event if you're the one changing the listbox... put your `Debug.Print` in the code that performs the filtering.

Comment: I would get rid of `On Error Resume Next` until you know the errors that appear (if any).  I would follow @MathieuGuindon's advice on this one.

Comment: FWIW `Erase NewList` is redundant, the array is local and already uninitialized...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When this change to the ListBox happens, I want to Debug.Print "A message..." but with no success.

**Reason**

The `ListBox_Change` event handler is executed only when the row selection changes (Any row whether selected or unselected in the ListBox is clicked) and **NOT** when the Listbox is cleared or an item is added.

**Alternative**

Couple of ways to capture the "change" caused by filter

1. Use `Debug.Print` (as @MathieuGuindon and @Kevinhiew suggested) /`Msgbox`/`Update a Label`/`Update Excel Statusbar` etc... in the `Combobox_Click` event.
2. Check the before and after `Listbox.Listcount`. This has a basic flaw that if the items changed but the list count didn't then this will not alert. You could counter that with the `filteredCount` in `Function FilterData()` to check if the array was changed.
3. After populating the listbox, select the first item using `If ListBox1.ListCount > 0 Then ListBox1.ListIndex = 0`

Answer (score -1):

Why not put the debug.print in the combo box when you select a value. While changing the row source, show the message as well.